# I there a better way than 'arr + arr[::-1][1:]'?

Tags: python, arrays, list, sorting

I just solved the task called 
'give me a diamond' on codewars.
https://www.codewars.com/kata/5503013e34137eeeaa001648
I created a pyramid in array using 
asterisks(*) and then expanded
array by reversed version of pyramid without first element.
I there a better way than pyramid + pyramid[::-1][1:]?

```py
    #               *
    #   *          ***
    #  ***   -->  *****
    # *****        ***
    #               *
    pyramid = ['  *\n',' ***\n','*****\n']
    return pyramid + pyramid[::-1][1:]
```

Comment: `x[::-1][1:] == x[-2::-1]`

Answer (score 0):

Here's a really simple solution:

```
num = int(input("enter size of you diamond:"))

for i in range(1, num+1):
  i = i - (num//2 +1)
  if i < 0:
    i = -i
  print(" " * i + "*" * (num - i*2) + " "*i)
```

output:

```
  *  
 *** 
*****
 *** 
  *
```